# Magento & Enhanced Ecommerce Google Analytics Script Issue

Tags: php, google-analytics, magento-1.9, enhanced-ecommerce

I am trying to simply add the checkout step in to my magento store. In an ideal world I would be able to add this into the GA script using:

```
ga('ec:setAction','checkout', {'step': 1});
```

As I can't insert this into the ga.php file, I am tring to work out if I can use push to insert this into the script. I have tried the datalayer push with no joy.

Any help would be gratefully appreciated.